# Задача на Python. Где ошибка?

Tags: python

Секция художественной гимнастики набирает девочек от 4 до 12 лет включительно. Напишите программу, которая запрашивает возраст и пол кандидата, используя обозначение пола буквами М и Ж, соответственно, и определяет, подходит ли кандидат для занятий в кружке. Если кандидат подходит, то выведите «ДА», иначе выведите «НЕТ».

```
age = int(input())
gender = input() 

if 4 <= age <= 12 and g == "Ж":
    print ("ДА")
else 
    print ("НЕТ")
```

Comment: А ты текст ошибки не осилил? Там же все написано.

Answer (score 1):

Вот правильный код:

```
age = int(input())
gender = input() 

if 4 <= age <= 12 and gender == "Ж":
    print ("ДА")
else:
    print ("НЕТ")
```

Ты не поставил двоеточие и сравниваешь неизвестную переменную.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Ну для начала после else нет двоеточия. И потом ты говоришь проверить g, а сам вводишь gender.